# Convert date string into a date timestamp

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-formatting

I have this field in a table that houses a date timestamp in this format (e.g '2023_11_20_23_18_03').

I am trying to find a way to convert this string field into a date field with the formatting ('YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:ss'). I can not seem to find a good way to parse this field out to create this new format besides using 'LEFT'/'RIGHT' functions.

I am trying to have the field show as '2023/12/31 21:18:03'

[image]

Comment: The specific dialect of SQL (Oracle, TSQL, Postgress, etc) you're using would be really helpful. The appropriate method may differ between dialects.

Comment: It's **rude and disrespectful** to those of us who might help you to use images in your question like that, because it makes us need to retype those tables and column names instead of copying from the question.  It's also an extra barrier that make it that much less likely you get a good answer at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Snowflake use [TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp?utm_source=snowscope&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=try_to_timestamp),

```
select $1 as str
    ,try_to_timestamp_ntz($1, 'yyyy_mm_dd_hh24_mi_ss') as ts
from values
('2023_12_20_23_18_03'),
('2023_11_01_10_18_03');
```

| STR | TS |
| --- | --- |
| 2023_12_20_23_18_03 | 2023-12-20 23:18:03.000 |
| 2023_11_01_10_18_03 | 2023-11-01 10:18:03.000 |

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand is database do not let you pick the format for date/datetime values. The database will keep these value the way it needs to be efficient for storage, indexing, and date operations, regardless of how you want to display them.

This means when calling `to_date()`, it's expecting the **input format**, not the result format, and you actually need to do **two operations**: one to convert the string to a date, and the other to convert the date a string in the desired format.

```
SELECT VERSION_CREATE_AT, to_char(to_date(VERSION_CREATED_AT, 'YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI_SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM US_OPS_ANALYTICS.UPLOADS.MV_US_LOGISTICS_FINAL_MILE_DETAIL
WHERE left(SCM_WEEK,4)='2024'
```

---

Also note you still had **months** in the minutes position, and assuming the question is tagged correctly, Snowflake needs to know if you wanted 12 or 24 -hour time.